# Can gdb print a specific variable every time it breaks?

Tags: gdb

I need to check a variable to find out if it is set correctly, which might be happening after several loops.

What I am doing now is something like follows:

```
(gdb) b myfile.cpp:180
(gdb) c
(gdb) p decoder.m_msg
(gdb) c
(gdb) p decoder.m_msg
(gdb) c
...
```

Can I have this variable `decoder.m_msg` automatically printed every time the program breaks?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, with [breakpoint command lists](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_34.html):

```
$ break myfile.cpp:180
Breakpoint 1 at 0x46ba0e: file myfile.cpp, line 180.

$ commands 1
> print decoder.m_msg
> end
$
```

Comment: Nice! I wasn't familiar with this!  `display` may not always work because a variable may be out of scope, but a command list solves that.

Answer (score 42):

Use the `display` command:

```
(gdb> display decoder.m_msg
```

This will cause `decoder.m_msg` to be printed every time that the prompt is shown (not only after a breakpoint).